# Problems with linking to other local pages in html

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, let me tell you that I don't even know if my problem can be solved. But I would really like some feedback.

Case:
We have implemented a narrowcasting solution at one of our customers. The solution allows for management via a web interface on the product. But since remembering and going to all the screens on after another, I made my own page to log into. Linking to all the displays in an Iframe.

Problem:
Going to my page locally works fine.
"href://ip:port"
Going to the page remotely (on dns) won't load the local screens. 
I figured this is due to the use of local ip-addresses.

Question:
How would someone solve this, and can this even be done?

I really like to hear what you guys/girls think.

Comment: Do the iframes use relative paths?

Comment: No, the path I used is href="http://192.1.1.1:8080"

Comment: That is why the iframes do not load then. Even though the page containing the iframes loads, it still tries to load the iframes, not with the domain, but with ip:port.

Comment: And by the way, you should have a `src` property in iframe elements not a `href`. Could you post the html source of the page?

Comment: `<a class="display" href="" target="iframe">screen</a>` and the iframe `<iframe name="iframe" src="#"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll need to ensure your content is on a web server (IIS/Apache etc)
2. You'll need to configure your router to forward ports `80` and `443` (HTTP & HTTPS) (If you are using other ports, forward them as well) through to the local ip of the PC with the web server.
3. You can then access the content through your external ip in the form of `http://{externalIP}:{port}/{pageURI}` *(NB. if the port is `80` you don't need to type it in the url)*

If you have any other questions, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Matt, while this does solve the problem. It leaves me exposing the screens directly to the outside world. Wich isn't ideal. I wil give it a try though.

Comment: @JohnWeijenberg I possibly misunderstood your question, sorry. How is the rest of the site secured from the outside world?

Comment: We used a nginx to ask for a uname and pass, before redirecting to our webserver. We do have acces to the firewall though, so I think we can do with forwarding and whitelisting only the correct ip.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone for coming up with solutions.
We used the solution Matt provided. With a bit of a twist. 
We made subdomains for all the different screens and routed them to the appropriate using nginx.